# Ribbon buttons are greyed out when using a custom form template

Tags: ribbon

So I've created a custom form template based on the default ListForm (haven't changed much there, basically just the title), I've set up a custom content type and I've added that to a Tasks list. When I try to create a new task, I see this:

[image]

Does anyone knows why the ribbon could be disabled in this case?

Comment: My Guess is that what you changed somehow corrupted the page. Have you tried undoing your change? Do the buttons come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved now. I was overwriting the default `window.onload` handler function for the iframe and thus preventing the ribbon from being initialized. I've switched to using jQuery to attach to the load event, and all works now.

Comment: Mihai hi can You describe your actions in more detail?

Comment: Just comment out all of your custom Javascript from that page/rendering template, and see if the problem goes away. Then add it back bit by bit, and be sure to attach event handlers to controls using jQuery or a similar library. The ribbon buttons are greyed out by default, and are enabled by a custom Sharepoint JS function executing on page load, so you must take care that your own Javascript doesn't throw any exceptions/doesn't overwrite the default `onload` handler for the pop-up edit window.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to above - the ribbon options were grey (gray) when I showed a list item using a Rendering Template.  The ribbon also showed a lot more options than you usually see when viewing an item.

My soltuion was simple though: I'd forgotton to include this line in the template:

```
<SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server"/>
```

Once in the correct, active ribbon appeared.

Hope this saves someone some time ...

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "haven't changed much there, basically just the title"?

I tried to reproduce your issue, but my form for Tasks list doesn't look like yours:

[image: my form]

Here what I have done:

1. Created new "Team Site" site collection
2. Opened Tasks list
3. Opened SharePoint Designer, created new form for the list, and marked it as the default
   [image: MyNewForm.aspx]
4. Saved all the changes

So, you should probably recreate your form template, or provide more information about your issue (especially about list and form customizations).